# how to check inserted regex pattern is valid or not

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi guys I have to create a demo project, to check if inserted regex pattern is valid or not.

I have one text box.

With help of this text-box, I am entering the regex for date, email, time, etc.
But I don't know how can I do this type of validation check.
Help me out with this.

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ygfQ8/9/

It's not perfect, but just a view of how I am checking the pattern using jquery.

```
$('input').on('blur',function(){
 var str = $('input').val();
var first = '(';
    var last = ')';
    var get_first =  str.charAt( str.length1 );
    var get_last = str.charAt( str.length -1 );
    if(first==get_first && last==get_last)
    {
        alert('patter is valid');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('pattern is invalid');
    }
});
```

and html textbox is `<input type='text'>`

This is php working demo:

```
<?php
//this variable containg any string .... doesnt matter wat ?
$subject = 'This is some text I am searching in'; //simple testing string variable
$pattern = '(fdsfdsfdsfdsfsd'; // user inputed string 
if(@preg_match($pattern, $subject) === false)
echo "YOU have entered wrong regex pattern";
else 
echo "Great work ";
?>
```

Comment: Would you like to check, if `last` and `first` characters are the same? Or if regular expression pattern is valid?

Comment: make a new Regex object in a try-catch block... if you don't get into the catch block, the pattern is valid.

Comment: @FSou1 want to check regular expression pattern is valid or not

Answer (score 0):

This could suit your needs:

```js
function isPatternValid(pattern) {
    try {
        "".match(new RegExp(pattern));
        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Calling with:

```js
$('#input').blur(function() {
    alert(isPatternValid(this.value));
});
```

Comment: @user2496644 Let `"".match(...)`, no need to put a fake value. The idea is just to check if the `match` method could run, whatever is returned. If it could not run, which means that the regex was not valid, an exception will be thrown, an catched by the `catch` block, thus `return false`.

Comment: hey check my this question :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075380/how-to-determine-entered-pattern-is-for-int-varchar-date-time-etc and also comment