# how to determine entered pattern is for `Int,VarChar,Date,Time...` etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have one drop-down its contain `DataType`.
and one text-box this this is for enter `Regex Pattern`. 
if I am enter `/test/` in textbox.
or select from drop-down `Int` 
then its wrong pattern if enter in text-box `/[0-9]/`
then its `correct pattern`.
 here is my fiddle link 
http://jsfiddle.net/VGF9B/2/

this is my `script`

```
var dropdownValue = 'selectValue';
$('select').change(function(){
    dropdownValue = $(this).val();
});
$('#pattern').focusout(function(){
    alert(dropdownValue);
    var pattern = new RegExp($('#pattern').val());
    alert(pattern);
});
```

How can its possible

Comment: What is your question? Can you please be clearer?

Comment: @tb11 how to determine entered pattern is for `Int,VarChar,Date,Time...` etc.

Comment: @tb11 int means `0-9` if i select `Int` from `drop-down` and enter pattern in textbox `/[a-z]/` => its wrong, `/[0-9]/`=>valid, `/\d{2}/`=>valid....

Comment: I think the question you're trying to ask is 'how can I validate that a regex string allows input that matches a data type'? Might be worth rewriting the question as it isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
var intRx=/^\d*$/;                            //22
var varCharRx=/^\w*$/;                        //abc
var dateRx=/^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/;            //01-01-2011
var time=/^\d{2}:\d{2}$/;                    //12:00

    str=$(this).val();        
    if(intRx.test(str))
        alert("int");
    else if(varCharRx.test(str))
        alert("varchar");
    else if(dateRx.test(str))
        alert("date");
    else if(time.test(str))
        alert("time");
```

Remember, this mathes the EXACT pattern, If you want some other exceptions, you will have to add that in the regex! and it is not for validation

http://jsfiddle.net/VGF9B/4/

Comment: not this type its check entered value with pattern i want to check pattern. is valid or not

Comment: you want to check if a pattern matches the entered value instead of checking if an entered value matches a pattern? it is the same thing! what do you mean by a pattern is valid or not?? every pattern is different and valid in it's own way!

Answer (score 0):

What I could think about is to use *examples*, i.e. typical inputs that should match the regex:

```js
var examples = {
    "Date": [
        "2010-01-01", "10-01-01", "2010-1-1", "10-1-1", "01-01-2010", "01-01-10", "1-1-2010", "1-1-10",
        "2010/01/01", "10/01/01", "2010/1/1", "10/1/1", "01/01/2010", "01/01/10", "1/1/2010", "1/1/10"
    ],
    "Int": [
        "0", "0123456789"
    ],
    "VarChar": [
        "a", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "A", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    ]
};
```

Then, if the input regex matches one of the type-specific example, you could valid it:

```js
$("#pattern").blur(function() {
    var pattern = this.value;
    var regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    var type = $("select").val();
    var validPattern = false;
    if (type in examples) {
        for (var i = 0; i < examples[type].length, i++) {
            var example = examples[i];
            if (regex.test(example)) {
                validPattern = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        alert("No examples found for type '" + type + "'");
    }
    if (validPattern) {
        alert("Valid pattern");
    } else {
        alert("Invalid pattern");
    }
});
```

The main problem is that it won't cover complex/special regexes. For example, `Int` with `/^5/` won't be valid with the given examples, since there's no `Int` example starting with `5`. `VarChar` with `/bca/` won't be valid neither. But if you manage to have enough examples for each type, this could suit your needs :)

You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VGF9B/5/).